# Change names in dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am working with the data midwest in R and I want to change the names in the first column which represents the counties to the counties_state, to avoid problems building graphics because there are counties in the same name in different states. How do I do that, I tried a for loop but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what info you've already have. but if you have the matched county to state, you could

```
test <-tibble(state=c("TX", "TX"), 
              county=c("X", "Y"))
test

test$new=paste0(test$state,"_", test$county)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked.  I cant upvote, otherwise I would!!

Comment: @AnaBranco You should be able to accept as an answer to your problem.